# How to hide QProgressBar digits progress feedback

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I would like to hide the `QProgressBar`'s digit feedback display. But I can't find a property responsible for it. Here is the screenshot showing it:

[image]

```
progressBar=QtGui.QProgressBar()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property you are looking for is the [`textVisible`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprogressbar.html#textVisible-prop) property.

```
progressbar.setTextVisible(False)
```